# Dúvida sobre desenvolvimento no firefox/firebug

Tags: google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, firefox, firebug

Normalmente trabalho com o Chrome para o desenvolvimento de sites, mas atualmente estou em um cliente que só usa Firefox e estou percebendo algumas diferenças.

Já pesquisei mas não encontrei muito sobre o assunto, quem trabalha a mais tempo com Firefox pode me ajudar a responder as seguintes perguntas:

- No Chrome consigo editar o javascript e fazer um rebuild em tempo de execução, no Firefox não consegui. Existe alguma forma de fazer?
- No Chrome os breakpoints continuam mesmo após você fechar o navegador, isso ajuda bastante entre um dia e outro. No Firefox, ao fechar a página, os breakpoints somem. Existe alguma forma de mantê-los?
- Alguma dica de Add-ons no Firefox?

Comment: Eu também tenho essas dúvidas. Pois eu desde de o ínicio eu utilizo o firebug no firefox, por influência, e acabei criando uma resistência em utilizar outros para o desenvolvimento. Mas, acaba que uso o firebug mesmo, só para alterações no css, e para execultar alguns testes de jquery no console.

Answer (score 1):

- No Chrome consigo editar o javascript e fazer um rebuild em tempo de execução, no Firefox não consegui. Existe alguma forma de fazer?

Não. É possível apenas que você execute comandos no console ou adicione pequenos scripts na barra de URL, mas nada além disso.

O grande problema de realizar alterações no Javascript, é em como estas alterações devem ser propagadas, e, portanto, o resultado de uma alteração pode não refletir o resultado da mesma caso o script tivesse acabado de ser servido do servidor.

- No Chrome os breakpoints continuam mesmo após você fechar o navegador, isso ajuda bastante entre um dia e outro. No Firefox, ao fechar a página, os breakpoints somem. Existe alguma forma de mantê-los?

Não. Não mesmo.

- Alguma dica de Add-ons no Firefox?

Baseado em opiniões, mas vamos lá. Acredito que esteja falando de extensões de desenvolvedor.

Utilize o Firefox Developer Edition. Ele não precisa de extensão alguma (até hoje pelo menos, não precisei).